# Не могу подключить файл к скрипту

Tags: php

Есть два файла **wt.php** и **api.php**.

**wt.php**:

```
<?php
    $rf = $_GET['name'];
?>
```

И **api.php**:

```
<?php

include_once 'wt.php';

if($rf==1) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
else {
    echo Dont_Authed;
}

?>
```

Открываю **wt.php?name=1** и **api.php**, всё должно работать, но к сожалению не робит.

Comment: Как именно выражается "не робит"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну конечно не работает, вы открываете два файла которые по сути ничего друг о друге не знают и данные между собой не передают. Каждый файл это новая сессия на сервер, они никак не взаимодействуют. 
Вам надо результат из `GET` Сохранить в сессию и уже
потом вы сможете ее использовать. Вот верный вариант.
**wt.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();//в самом начале
    $_SESSION['rf'] = $_GET['name'];
```

**api.php**

```
   include_once 'wt.php';

   if($_SESSION['rf'] == 1) {
       header('Location: index.php');
   }   else {
       echo Dont_Authed;
   }
```

Теперь после последовательного вызова **wt.php** и **api.php** вас с параметром `name=1` с редиректит на `index.php`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76797/discussion-on-answer-by--------).

Comment: Да да, извините пожалуйста.